# Output last inserted primary key value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I'm having a bit of difficulty with this one in that I'm not sure how to do this in SQL Server.

Basically, I want to insert a new row into the database, get the PK value that was just inserted (same query) and output it back to whatever called the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Users_Insert
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @userid int output,
    @name varchar(50),
    @surname varchar(50),
    @email varchar(200),
    @password varchar(50),
    @location varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into Users(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, Location)
    values(@name, @surname, @email, @password, @location);
    GO
    @userid = @@IDENTITY;
END
```

I've done this in MySQL as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Users_Insert(@userid int output, @name varchar(50), @surname varchar(50), @email varchar(200), @password varchar(50), @location varchar(50)
BEGIN

    insert into Users(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, Location)
    values(@name, @surname, @email, @password, @location);

    set @userid = last_insert_id();
END
```

SQL Server gives me an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Users_Insert, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near '@userid'.

Frankly, I'm not sure I declared the output parameter correctly, can anyone offer suggestions?

Comment: Select SELECT @userid= SCOPE_IDENTITY(); and remove go its not necessary.

Comment: marc_s doesn't like my lazy typing :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to **assign** the value to `@userid` ! Also, I would recommend using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and not `@@IDENTITY` :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Users_Insert
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @userid int output,
    @name varchar(50),
    @surname varchar(50),
    @email varchar(200),
    @password varchar(50),
    @location varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into Users(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, Location)
    values(@name, @surname, @email, @password, @location);

    -- make an actual **assignment** here...
    SELECT @userid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

[See this blog post for an explanation as to **WHY** you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` over `@@IDENTITY`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @Ortund: you had **no assigment** - you just had `@userid = ...` - not `SET` or `SELECT` keyword

Comment: `Must declare the scalar varialbe "@userid"` ... whenever I get onto sql server, it's all just problems, problems, problems... this is why I moved to mysql >_>

Comment: The `GO` in the middle of the procedure is not valid. @Ortund - If you don't type valid syntax yes that will cause you problems. Sure that is the same in MySQL too.

Comment: Now I'm getting `An SqlParameter with ParameterName '' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.` ... I assume this means that the SP is expecting a parameter called '' ?

Comment: @Ortund: that's a problem in your **calling** code (C# or VB.NET) - that's a totally different question - ask it as a separate question.

Comment: issue with scope identity...........http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/